# Calculate order from given value of Bessel Function of first kind

Tags: bessel-functions

I am given the Bessel function of first kind of order $n$, $$J_n(\beta)= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^\pi \cos(\beta \sin x-nx)dx.$$ $n$ is positive integer. It's value is known as $J_n(\beta)\geq0.01$ for a particular $\beta$, meaning I need to find out the maximum $n$ for which the function doesn't fall below $0.01$. How can I determine the order $n$ from this?

Comment: If $n$ is real, $J_n$ has infinitely many positive real zeros. Thus, your inequality cannot hold with any particular real $n$ for all $\beta \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Here $n$ is positive integer only and $\beta$ is also given

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that a positive integer is also a real number? Thus, $J_1,J_2,J_3,\ldots$ all have infinitely many positive real zeros.

Comment: I want to find out $n$ for a given $\beta$.

Comment: I do not think there is a simple way to solve this problem. The maximal $n$ will depend in a nontrivial way on $\beta$.